# Table with columns with columns

Tags: tables

How can one make the following table with columns within columns?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show us your code ...

Comment: I have not created a table before! Just checked Table overleaf here https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Tables, but it does show anything like what I need. I  am using the following document class: \documentclass[pra,onecolumn]{revtex4}.

Comment: You need to define so may columns as you needed on table body and than put `Action 1` and `Action 2`  into `\multicolumn{2}{c}{ <content> }`. BTW, columns cannpot be split to "sub" columns, but cells in adjacent columns can be merged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing particularly special about your table. Just use a couple of `\multicolumn` directives for the cells that span two columns.

To have the decimal markers show up as `\cdot` (raised dot) symbols and to align the numbers in the four data columns on the decimal markers, I suggest you load the `siunitx` package, employ its `S` column type instead of basic-LaTeX `c` column type, and run `\sisetup{output-decimal-marker=\cdot}`.

[image]

Observe that non-numeric cell contents such as `\alpha` and `\beta` are encased in curly braces; this informs the `siunitx` package that the cell contents shouldn't be processed further and just be centered horizontally.

```
\documentclass[pra]{revtex4}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for 'S' column type

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker=\cdot} % optional
\caption{A 5-column table}
\begin{tabular}{ | l | *{4}{S[table-format=1.2]|} }
\hline
Class & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Action 1} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Action 2} \\
\cline{2-5}
& {$\alpha$} & {$\beta$} & {$\alpha$} & {$\beta$} \\ \hline
C1 & 1.01 & 0.1 & 1.3 & 1.5  \\ \hline
C2 & 0.1  & 1.3 & 1.5 & 1.01 \\ \hline
C3 & 3.0  & 3.1 & 0.4 & 1.2  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\the\tabcolsep
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let me spell out my comment, but now with considering `tabularray` package and its syntax for `multirow` and `multicolumn` cells:

```
\documentclass{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx} % for 'S' column type

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines, 
             colspec={c Q[c, si={table-format=1.2}, wd=2em] % S column type
                   *{2}{Q[c, si={table-format=1.1}, wd=2em]}
                        Q[c, si={table-format=1.2}, wd=2em]
                      },
             }
\SetCell[r=2]{c} Class  % <--- multi row cell
    & \SetCell[c=2]{c} {{{Action 1}}}   % <--- multi column cell in S column type
            &       &  \SetCell[c=2]{c} {{{Action 2}}}    
                            &           \\
    & $\alpha$
            & $\beta$
                    & $\alpha$ 
                            & $\beta$   \\ 
C1  & 1.01  & 0.1   & 1.3   & 1.5       \\ 
C2  & 0.1   & 1.3   & 1.5   & 1.01      \\ 
C3  & 3.0   & 3.1   & 0.4   & 1.2       \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. However, `nicematrix` is not compatible with the class `revtex4`. I have used the class `revtex4-1` (which is also obsolete...).

```
\documentclass[pra]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for 'S' column type
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker=\cdot} % optional
\caption{A 5-column table}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{l*{4}{S[table-format=1.2]}}[hvlines]
\Block{2-1}{} Class & \Block{1-2}{Action 1} && \Block{1-2}{Action 2} \\
& {$\alpha$} & {$\beta$} & {$\alpha$} & {$\beta$} \\ 
C1 & 1.01 & 0.1 & 1.3 & 1.5  \\ 
C2 & 0.1  & 1.3 & 1.5 & 1.01 \\ 
C3 & 3.0  & 3.1 & 0.4 & 1.2  \\ 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

However, I would recommend a tabular in the style of `booktabs`.